# XPTY0002 contextItem

Tags: java, xml, xquery, sax, saxon

I want to execute an xQuery file on an XML file ; When compiling the query, I have the following error. I do not understand this "context item" error.

**CODE (example)**

```
String xmlFileName = "D:/fichierContenu.XML";
FileInputStream XmlStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFileName);

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xmlFileName);
InputSource is = new InputSource(fis);
Document doc = builder.parse(is);

Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();

InputStream queryStream = queryStream = new FileInputStream("D:/TestsAuto.xq");
Processor proc = new Processor(false);
XQueryCompiler comp = proc.newXQueryCompiler();
XQueryExecutable exp = comp.compile(queryStream);
```

**XQuery**

```
declare function local:checkRefTest() as xs:string {
    (:text and explication here. :)
    let $REFTEST := /dmodule/descendant::REFTEST  ***(=> line 363 HERE)***
    return 
        let $refTestKO := 
            for $item in $REFTEST
            return
                if(fn:string-length($item/@RefTest)= 13) then
                    let $RefTest := fn:substring($item/@RefTest, 1, 6)
                    return
                        if ($RefTest = "      ") then
                            if(fn:exists($item/@refval) and fn:exists($item/@refval2)) then 
                                ()
                            else
                                ()
                        else 
                            ()
                else
                    $item
        return 
            if(fn:empty($refTestKO)) then
                "OK"
            else
                fn:concat("NOK : test here ", "'",fn:string-join($refTestKO/@RefTest, "', '"),"'")
};
```

**ERROR**

Error on line 363 of module with no systemId:
**XPDY0002: Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the tree containing the context item**:
the context item is undefined
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the tree containing the context item: the context item is undefined
at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XQueryCompiler.compile(XQueryCompiler.java:504)
at utils.xquery.essai.main(essai.java:92)
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the tree containing the context item: the context item is undefined
at net.sf.saxon.expr.SingleNodeExpression.typeCheck(SingleNodeExpression.java:29)
at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionVisitor.typeCheck(ExpressionVisitor.java:206)

Could you explain or show me a piece of code that would allow me to solve this concern ?
What is my problem ?

Comment: How about looking at line 363 and sharing it here if you can't figure it out? Or better yet try to reduce the code to a minimum to reproduce the problem and post the complete code. Is that code inside a function for instance?

Comment: `declare function local:checkRefTest() as xs:string {  
    (:text and explication here. :)  
    let $REFTEST := /dmodule/descendant::REFTEST  (=> line 363 here)  
    return   
        let $refTestKO :=   
            for $item in $REFTEST`
  [...]

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#FunctionDeclns, for a user defined function, "its context item static type component is absent". So I think your code declaring a function but trying to access `/` assuming a context node is not going to work, you would need to declare a parameter for that function and pass a node into when calling the function and use e.g. `declare function local:checkRefTest($input) as xs:string { (:text and explication here. :) let $REFTEST := $input/dmodule/descendant::REFTEST`.

Comment: Is there a solution if I can't modify the file of my client ?It's a file from a industrial and  I can't modify it :(

Comment: If the code has an error I think that error needs to be fixed. If it is generated by some tool then that tool needs to be fixed. Or it is meant to be executed by some more lenient XQuery processor but I am afraid I don't know in which context that code is supposed to be used.